# HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc, spring-validator

I am working on a Spring MVC application and have an issue with the validation. I need to create an user and it is a 2 step process(meaning 2 jsps with the same controller). The jsps have 2 different commandNames. So when I created the validator for the first model and initialize it, the first page loads fine. For testing, I am not using an if condition, but forwarding to next page. I get an error as the controller tries to load the validator with the current commandName object and it fails.

When I enter the url http://ip:port/data, the page loads as there is no validation, it is just initial load
When I try to submit the page without entering the firstName and submit, the method @RequestMapping(value = "/user") is called and the the next page 2 is supposed to be loaded. But the page 2 fails.

```
binder.getTarget() prints UserData the first time which is right
binder.getTarget() prints userinfo the 2nd time, when the next page is loading and it fails with the error
```

StackTrace:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid target for Validator [.validator.UserDataValidator@4366febc]: .model.UserInfo@4e3a061b

type Exception report

message Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid target for Validator [.validator.UserDataValidator@4366febc]: .model.UserInfo@4e3a061b

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid target for Validator [.validator.UserDataValidator@4366febc]: .model.UserInfo@4e3a061b
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)

root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid target for Validator [.validator.UserDataValidator@4366febc]: .model.UserInfo@4e3a061b
    org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.assertValidators(DataBinder.java:516)
    org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.setValidator(DataBinder.java:507)
    .controller.AccountDataController.initBinder(AccountDataController.java:65)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    org.springframework.web.method.annotation.InitBinderDataBinderFactory.initBinder(InitBinderDataBinderFactory.java:62)
    org.springframework.web.bind.support.DefaultDataBinderFactory.createBinder(DefaultDataBinderFactory.java:53)
    org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelFactory.updateBindingResult(ModelFactory.java:251)
```

Any suggestions on how to handle this would be helpful. Is there a way to make this work - having 2 different commandNames and trying to validate using one controller or do I need to update the commandName to one object and that object has all the classes inside it.

```
e.g.

class Parent{
 UserData UserData;
 UserInfo userInfo;

 getter & setter
}
```

My Controller:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("userData")
public class AController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDataValidator")
    private Validator validator;

    @InitBinder
    private void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {

        System.out.println("getTarget: "+binder.getTarget()); ------------ 
        binder.setValidator(validator);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/data", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String initForm(Model model){

        UserData userData = new UserData();
        model.addAttribute("userData", userData);
        return "page1";

    }//

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method=RequestMethod.POST )
    public String details(Model model, @Validated UserData userData, BindingResult result) {
        *****
        model.addAttribute("userinfo", userinfo);
        return "page2";

    }//
    **EDIT**
    @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method=RequestMethod.POST )
*****************
public String create(Model model, Userinfo userinfo, UserData userData) {

*********************user creation
}
**EDIT**
}
```

My JSPs

```
page1.jsp

<form:form method="POST" action="user" commandName="userData">
    <form:label path="firstName"><b>Name</b></form:label> <br />
    <form:input class="formLabel" path="firstName" />
    ****
</form>

page2.jsp

 <form:form method="POST" action="create" commandName="userinfo">
 ***********fields
 </form>
```

My validator

```
public class UserDataValidator  implements Validator{

    public boolean supports(Class<?> paramClass) {
        return UserData.class.equals(paramClass);

    }

    public void validate(Object obj, Errors errors) {
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "firstName", "valid.firstName");

    }

}
```

My Model

```
UserData.java

public class UserData {

    String firstName;

    getter & setter for firstName

}
```

Let me know if any more details are needed. Thanks.

Comment: You're not showing us the code my guess is that the problem precisely comes from the part you chose to hide), and you also don't provide the stack trace. Show us the real code.

Comment: Thanks. I have added the complete stacktrace and updated my controller. I did not display the whole code to avoid even longer post.

Comment: Basically my questions is - can we have multiple validators(these are multiple model objects) in one single controller?